# Java checking the status of threads by using another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program where a bunch of threads carry out some task. I want to know when all these threads are finished so that I can do some other stuff with their results. I don't want to use things like `Thread.join`. What I prefer is another thread checking on all these threads and when it sees that they are finished, it carries out some special task. Any ideas about how this can be done ?

Comment: you could use a bunch of TimerTasks instead and they could return a value when they are complete

Comment: And why don't you want to use `join`?

Comment: Cause the current screen gets stuck (I am developing for blackberry)

Comment: That's a bit like wanting to add two BigIntegers without using the add() method. There are other ways, but Thread.join() does exactly what you want. Why not using it?

Comment: How about using groups for all threads and then calling `activeCount()` on any of the group's thread?

Comment: You should of course not call `Thread.join()` from the UI thread. Call it from another, additional thread.

Comment: @JBNizet actually that's a good idea will try that and see what happens

Comment: @JBNizet and it works! all the answers are good but this was the simplest and most intuitive one.. if it was an answer I would've marked it as correct;)

Comment: Tomasz's and Peter's answers are excellent answers, which show you good alternatives to `Thread.join()`. And those alternatives also block the current thread. It's just that your question should rather have been: how to wait for working threads to finish without blocking the UI thread? Instead on focusing on the problem (blocked UI thread), you ruled out an obvious solution without saying why.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah I guess you are right sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually blocking is much easier to implement, more reliable and does not introduce any extra overhead/latency. If you don't want to use `join()`, consider [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), which allows you to wait for a set of threads.

Another, much more pleasant approach is [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) wrapped with lightweight [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).

Both approaches can be used in a non-blocking fashion, e.g. only peeking rather than blocking and waiting for a result. But in order not to waste CPU cycles, have a separate background thread blocking and waiting for a result and sending some event immediately when all worker threads are done.

Alternatively let each worker thread send an event when it's done. The object that receives these events will know the processing is done once the number of received events reaches the number of workers started. With [`ListenableFuture`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) from Guava you can even avoid extra *watchdog* thread.

Answer (score 4):

I would use an ExecutorService like

```
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
for(int i = 0; i < N_TASKS; i++)
    futures.add(executorService.submit(new Task(i));

// wait for all tasks to complete.
for(Future future : futures) future.get();
```